# many to many in excel power pivot

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, powerpivot

I understand that working with many to many table structures in power pivots could be complex:

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/marco_russo/archive/2009/12/07/many-to-many-relationships-in-powerpivot.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alberto_ferrari/archive/2010/10/19/powerpivot-and-many-to-many-relationships.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

Actually this complexity is beyond sufferance for average PowerPivot user.

But how about "keep it simple" there?

Correct me if I'm wrong.

1. If you have fact table and index table (or many of them) - you can enjoy
   them in PowerPinvots using references. Index table there - table with PK.
2. But if structure become more  complex, and you need to reference e.g. 
   attribute through many to many  tables, then **just include this attribute 
   to the fact table and you will not face all those DAX complexities**. 
   This could means actually creating another fact table. E.g. if we have difficulties with referencing structures like this [image] 
   we still are able to create new fact table like this: [image]
3. If you become worried about fact table's size - migrate from tabular to
   multidimensional model.

What I have missed? Where is my logic is wrong?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want be sure that I'm thinking correctly. It is like I know an answer but also I'm not sure in it and want to find the authority on superuser. Could you help me to improve my question?

Comment: Not really, I don't know Excel very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new fact table: AccountFacts will give incorrect results 
when selecting the customerId.

In the Example of Marco Russo, an Account is shared with 2 customers. 
The new fact table can only hold the amount for 1 of the 2 customers, otherwise 
you're total amount will be to high (when not selecting a customer).

Comment: Thank you, that what I have missed. I should re-think everything.But I still feeling that for every aggregation "goal"  flat fact table could be created  and it is more perspective way than DAX tricks.

Comment: Now I got it. Marco solving really not a problem of "support" Many To Many referenecs. But "overriding" the calculation of total. So the  generic task is: when we design pivot, we actually design drill down and "calculating totals". So we should understand how powerpivot loops over the data and where we have extensibility points. WimV, if you know the article where it was explained how "powerpivot" loops through the data, please share it with me...